# Front end printing emulator `paper.css` not working with background color

Tags: html, css, printing, colors, background-color

I am using a solution, called [`paper.css`](https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css), to emulate a printed text which is type-set in html using these css rules.

I noticed that when I create an element with `background-color`, and then use my `Chromium` Print menu to "Save as PDF", the background color becomes white, just like the whole page.

How one can print the html file to pdf and still keep the background color?

A MMW, based on the [A4 example](https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css/blob/master/examples/a4.html) in the project's repository, is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper-css/0.4.1/paper.css">
  <style>
    @page {
      size: A4
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="A4">

  <!-- Each sheet element should have the class "sheet" -->
  <!-- "padding-**mm" is optional: you can set 10, 15, 20 or 25 -->
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm">

    <!-- Write HTML just like a web page -->
    <article style="background-color: red;">This is an A4 document.</article>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Compare with the printed PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the `More settings > Options > Background graphics` option checked in the Chrome print dialog.

Comment: I didn't find these setting in Chrome, but reached them in Firefox.  This indeed keeps the background color. Thanks!

Comment: In Chrome I use CTRL+P to get to the print dialog. That is where I see `More settings` in the right pane of the print dialog.

Comment: Mistake for me. I see it in Chrome too.